# MSP430-HC05 There is nothing at Serial Monitor

Tags: embedded, msp430, hc-05

I'm trying to send AT commands to HC05 for get other device names and rssi values.I'm using MSP-EXP430G2ET and HC05 module, pin connections are:

MSP  HC05

RX(P1.1)   TX

TX(P1.2)   RX

GND        GND

3.3V      VCC

EN and STATE pins are empty. (I don't know are theese necessary)

And here is my main file :

```
    #include <msp430.h>

    // HC-05 baud rate
    #define BAUD_RATE 9600

    // Buffer length for UART communication
    #define BUFFER_LENGTH 20

    // HC-05 UART pins
    #define HC05_TX BIT1
    #define HC05_RX BIT2

    // Delay function
    void delay(unsigned int d) {
        volatile unsigned int i;
        for(i=0; i<d; i++);
    }

    // Initialize UART
    void uart_init() {
        P1SEL |= HC05_TX + HC05_RX;
        P1SEL2 |= HC05_TX + HC05_RX;
        UCA0CTL1 |= UCSSEL_2;
        UCA0BR0 = 104;
        UCA0BR1 = 0;
        UCA0MCTL = UCBRS0;
        UCA0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;
    }

    // Send a character through UART
    void uart_send_char(char c) {
        while(!(IFG2 & UCA0TXIFG));
        UCA0TXBUF = c;
    }

    // Send a string through UART
    void uart_send_string(char* str) {
        int i;
        for(i=0; str[i]!=0; i++) {
            uart_send_char(str[i]);
        }
    }

    // Receive a character through UART
    char uart_receive_char() {
        while(!(IFG2 & UCA0RXIFG));
        return UCA0RXBUF;
    }

    // Receive a string through UART
    void uart_receive_string(char* buffer) {
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<BUFFER_LENGTH; i++) {
            buffer[i] = uart_receive_char();
            if(buffer[i] == '\r') {
                break;
            }
        }
        buffer[i] = 0;
    }

    // Send an AT command and wait for response
    void hc05_send_at_command(char* command, char* response) {
        char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
        int i;

        uart_send_string(command);
        delay(100000);
        uart_receive_string(buffer);
        for(i=0; buffer[i]!=0; i++) {
            response[i] = buffer[i];
        }
        response[i] = 0;
    }

    int main(void) {
        WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;

        uart_init();

        char response[BUFFER_LENGTH];

        // Send AT command to HC-05 and wait for response
        hc05_send_at_command("AT\r\n", response);

        // Print response
        uart_send_string("Response: ");
        uart_send_string(response);

        while(1);

        return 0;
    }
```

I asked Chat GPT to write this, it looks correct to me but when i open terminal screen in Code Composer Studio there is nothing happens.
Should I use USB-TTL Converter ?

I tried
connect EN pin to 3.3V (Nothing changed so I cut that connection).
open a PuTTY terminal but nothing changed again.

Comment: Is there communication on the physical level? Did you see voltages on the line jump? Did you check some existing tutorials/solutions? You're definitely not the first one with this hello-world-class project.